# echo out loop array, strange behaviour, php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sorting, alphabetical-sort

I'm using this code I found on the net to output links.

https://2buntu.com/articles/1301/php-script-to-dynamically-generate-links-to-the-files-present-in-current-directory/

```
    <?php
    $dir_open = opendir('.');

    while(false !== ($filename = readdir($dir_open))){
        if($filename != "." && $filename != ".."){
            $link = "<a href='./$filename'> $filename </a><br />";
            echo $link;
        }
    }

    closedir($dir_open);
    ?>
```

Now I would like to sort alphabetically, so I put into an array, sort and output. However I get some strange repeating output, with 100x more results than should be. what is going on here?

```
<?php
$dir_open = opendir('./myfolder/');

while(false !== ($filename = readdir($dir_open))){
    if($filename != "." && $filename != ".."){
        $array[] = "<a href='./myfolder/'> $filename </a><br />";
        sort($array, SORT_NATURAL);
        foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
            echo $val;
        }
    }
}

closedir($dir_open);
?>
```

full code

```
<?php
$dir_open = opendir('./suburblist/');

while(false !== ($filename = readdir($dir_open))){

    if($filename != "." && $filename != ".." && $filename != (preg_match('/\.html$/i', $filename))) {

        $domfilename = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $filename);        
        $domfilename = str_replace("-", " ", "$domfilename");
        $domfilename = ucwords("$domfilename");   
        $array[] = $domfilename;
    }
}

sort($array, SORT_NATURAL);

foreach ($array as $val) {

    echo "<a href='/suburblist/$filename'>$val </a>"; 
}

closedir($dir_open);
?>
```

Comment: Do you understand that you sort array on every `while` iteration?

Comment: It makes no sense to try to sort without enough results to sort to begin with. Instead store the directory file names in an arrray. When it finishes, sort that array once. Then finally loop through it and echo your pretty HTML links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is:

- get all filenames in array
- sort array **once**
- output sorted array **once**

---

```
// get all filenames in array
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dir_open))){
    if($filename != "." && $filename != ".."){
        $array[] = $filename;
    }
}

// sort array
sort($array, SORT_NATURAL);

// output values from array
foreach ($array as $val) {
    echo "<a href='./myfolder/'> $val </a><br />";
}
```

Two vars update:

```
// get all filenames in array
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dir_open))){
    if($filename != "." && $filename != ".."){
        $array[] = ['name' => $filename, 'link' => 'another value'];
    }
}

// sort array with custom function, as your array is multidimensional now:
usort(
    $array, 
    function ($a, $b) { return strnatcmp($a['name'], $b['name']); }
);

// output values from array
foreach ($array as $val) {
    echo "<a href='./myfolder/" . $val['link'] . "'>" . $val['name'] . "</a><br />";
}
```

Comment: I use a variable for <a href=/myfolder/$filename link, and it doesn't seem to output this way.

Comment: I don't know how you use your variable so either debug you code or modify question with relevant data.

Comment: code update, basically I have 2 $vars, one for the link and stripped one for the display.